# VS Code remote doesn't display symbols (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-remote

I installed VSCode on my remote host with the C/C++ extension pack. However, it seems that it doesn't display symbols properly, as the dropdown is empty apart from this message:

> "The active editor does not provide symbol information"

Usually I can press Ctrl-Shift-O to display symbol names (or click the ellipsis (...) in the breadcrumb path). This works on my local installation of vscode, however for some reason it doesn't in the remote.

[image: Symbol display not working in VSCode]

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 locally and Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.2 (Plow) on the server.

Comment: is this something where you need to install the C/C++ extension on the remote side too?

Comment: @starball I did though :/